# Spark: Find most common value from column of text file

Tags: apache-spark

I have a space-delimited text file of the format: [string] [string] [int] [int]. I am trying to extract the second column of this file, which contains words separated by "_", and find the most frequently occurring word (from all of the lines in the text file). So far, I have this scala code:

```
val wc = file
  .map(l => l.split(" "))
  .map{ case Array(a,b,c,d) => (b,1) }
  .map{ case (k,v) => k.split("_") }
```

Using `wc.first()` shows that a single entry of this RDD is in the format `Array[String] = Array(word1, word2,...)`

The next step for me was to use the `map` function to extract (key,value) pairs from the above data structure so that each word becomes `(word, 1)`. Then, I can reduce this output to find the word with the most occurrences. What can I use to finish this step? Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is the classic WordCount problem in Big Data in addition to a Sort operation. The following is an example:

```scala
val result =  file
        // splitting each line by space, followed by selecting the second column 
        // and splitting the second column text by "_" character
        .flatMap(line => line.split("\\s+")(1).split("_"))
        // now each line of the rdd is a single word, 
        // so we map each word to the (key, value) pair of (word, 1) 
        .map(word => (word, 1))
        // finally we reduce the (key, value) pairs by key and sum the values
        .reduceByKey((num1 , num2) => num1 + num2)
        // as you need the most common word, we sort rdd descending by values 
        .sortBy(_._2, false)
```

Suppose the input text file contains:

```scala
I hello_hi_world 1 1
you hi_world 1 1
he hi 2 3
she world_hi 4 5
```

and

```scala
println(result.take(3).toList)
```

will print the first three records of the `result` rdd which show the most frequent words in the second column of the input file

```scala
List((hi,4), (world,3), (hello,1))
```

Comment: I'd still suggest SparkSQL rather than RDD for this

Comment: @cricket_007 I'm curious as the input is in the form of the text file, does the SparkSession object provide a method for loading them directly, other than using SparkContext Object for loading text files and then convert them to DataFrame using the `toDf` method?

Comment: [`spark.read.text(path)`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader@text(path:String):org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame)